# Quickly Large Data Pivoting

Tags: sql, pivot, data-modeling, business-intelligence, large-data

We are developing a product which can be used for developing predictive models and the slicing and dicing of the data in order to provide BI.

We are having two kind of data access requirements.

For predictive modeling, we need to read data on daily basis and do it row by row. In this the normal SQL Server database is sufficient and we are not getting any issues.

In case of slicing and dicing data of huge sizes like 1GB of data having let us say 300 M rows. We want to pivot that data easily with minimum response time.

The current SQL Database is having response time issues in this.

We like our product to run on any normal client machine with 2GB RAM with Core 2 Duo processor.

I would like to know how should I store this data and then how I can create a pivoting experience for each of the dimension.

Ideally we will have data of let us say daily sales by sales person by region by product for a large corporation. Then we would like to slice and dice it based on any dimension and also be able to perform aggregation, unique values, maximum, minimum, average values and some other statistical functions.

Comment: What have you tried?  What's your data structure? What version of SQL Server? How often does data grow or is it static?  Is there a lot of insert/update activity?  How many users per DB?

Comment: We have used SQL Server 2008. First thing is this is not a transaction application. We are allowing user to import any such data and then do slicing and dicing as per their requirements. You can compare it with features of ClickView and SpotFire. So we do not have any insert/update activities regularly they import the data and then do analysis. The users will be around 50 per database.

Answer (score 1):

I would build an in-memory cube on top of that data. To give you an example, [icCube](http://www.icCube.com) is having sub-second response time for 3/4 measures over 50M rows on a single core i5 - without any cache or pre-aggregation (i.e., this response time is constant in all the dimensions).

Contact us directly for more details about how to integrate it into your product.

Comment: Our application is dynamic in nature. The measures and dimensions are user defined, so I do not think we can create cubes beforehand. Due to that reason, I am not sure how we can use icCube.

Comment: It's better to contact then directly (http://www.iccube.com/company/contact-us). icCube is quite flexible in many different ways and cube definitions could be created on demand.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [PowerPivot](http://www.powerpivot.com/) to do this. This is a free addin for Excel 2010, which would allow large data sets to be handled, sliced+diced, etc.

If you want to code around it, you can connect to the PowerPivot database [(effectively an SSAS cube](http://powerpivottwins.com/2009/11/07/for-excel-powerpivot-the-database-is-in-the-workbook/)) using the [SSAS database connector](http://dennyglee.com/2010/10/27/can-i-access-powerpivot-via-a-data-access-api/)

Hope that is of some use..

Comment: This is definitely useful. I will check out on this and if needed will revert back to you. Actually we are looking in the direction to integrate power pivot with .Net tools without need of excel.